# Laravel eagerly loaded model condition

Tags: laravel

I have two models, **Author** and **Book**

```
$authors = App\Author::with(['books' => function ($q){
    $q->where('name', 'like', '%foo%');
}])->where('status', 1);
```

As per given query this will return all the authors where status is 1 along with the books of matching conditions.

What I am seeking here is, if conditions in the closure return empty set of books. I don't want that author to be returned in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try `whereHas`

```
$authors = App\Author::with('books')
    ->whereHas('books', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%foo%');
    })->where('status', 1)
      ->get();
```

Docs (not sure which Laravel version you're on): https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations (and the header **Querying Relationship Existence**)